# how to access views in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, findviewbyid

I am new in android and I have been created simple app which have 3 tabs that I build them with Fragment Activity .

in Activities we can use findViewById method . but Fragments don't have this method . how can I access to my views ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your `getAcivity()` method within your fragment class to call the **context** of your `activity` that is bounded in it and after you can call `findViewById()`;

**sample:**

```
public void onViewCreated() 
    TextView txSample = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.yourid);
```

Comment: i think you meant getView(), not getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simple_lights, container, false);
    tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourid);
    return load;
}
```

You would better do all the view-related operations in onCreateView() and all the functional operations in onActivityCreated()